# Как спарсить номер телефона , если последние 4 числа скрыты до нажатии кнопки?

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
url = 'https://blizko.ru/gde_kupit_kvartiru/agentstva_nedvizhimosti'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
bio = soup.find_all('p', class_='cli-description')
name = soup.find_all('a', class_='cli-title js-cli-title js-ykr-action')
number = soup.find_all('span', class_='"phone-')
for i in range(0, len(bio)):
    print(bio[i].text)
    print('--' + name[i].text + number[i].text)
```

Это моя попытка спаристь - неудачно
Вот сайт : https://blizko.ru/gde_kupit_kvartiru/agentstva_nedvizhimosti?page=1
И нужно спарсить номера телефонов, но как это сделать, не используя selenium?

Comment: Используй requests_html :)

Comment: @СергейШ Я конечно попробую позже, но сейчас requests нужно юзать :(